# remote Edge webdriver is not launching

Tags: java, ruby, selenium, microsoft-edge

I have MicrosoftWebDriver that started as part of a standalone selenium server as such:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.52.0.jar -role node -hub http://192.168.11.56:4444/grid/register -Dwebdriver.edge.driver="C:\Users\Test\Desktop\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" -browser browserName=MicrosoftEdge
```

and I have a ruby code

```
def visitor
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.edge
  caps[:platform] = "WIN10"
  @agent_join = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, :url => "http://192.168.11.56:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => caps)
end
```

However, I get error

```
   09:04:41.465 INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=any, platformVersion=any, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, takesScreenshot=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesElementScreenshot=false, platformName=any, platform=WIN10}]])
09:04:41.512 INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{acceptSslCerts=false, browserVersion=any, platformVersion=any, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, takesScreenshot=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, takesElementScreenshot=false, platformName=any, platform=WIN10}]
Listening on http://localhost:32399/
Stopping server.
09:04:43.309 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-IP7V200', ip: '192.168.11.161', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:202)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:164)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:130)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
        at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
        at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
        at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-IP7V200', ip: '192.168.11.161', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unknown error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 656 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-IP7V200', ip: '192.168.11.161', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:152)
        at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:120)
        ... 14 more
09:04:43.590 WARN - Exception: Unknown error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 656 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-IP7V200', ip: '192.168.11.161', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver
```

Any idea how to resolve it?
ChromeDriver works fine. It's only the driver for Edge that's problematic.

Comment: Are you sure that's the complete stacktrace? Please post the whole thing if you have it.

Comment: Can you confirm that `C:\Users\Test\Desktop\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` is valid? Also have you tried without the `-browser browserName=MicrosoftEdge`?

Comment: Yes, the path of webdriver is valid. I have chrome driver in the same path, and that executes as expected. Regarding, `browserName=MicrosoftEdge`, I do start the server with that param

Comment: It turned out I had uninstalled Edge at some point. I've completely forgotten about it. I tried it on an VM I have, and it works fine. WOWW. just wow
The fact it was Win10, automatically led me to believe, I still have Edge.

Comment: Glad it's working, feel free to answer your own question and accept the answer so others can see how what worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have the latest MsEdge-Win10-VMware (currently Build number:20150801). I had an older version, which caused the selenium server to break.